# Stellate EEG Machine, would like to read the input in real-time, need to jury-rig it

Tags: eeg

I don't have an electrical engineering background but a neuroscience one, so apologies in advance for my poor knowledge.

Basically I have an EEG machine (Stellate Harmonie) and I would like to be able to read the data in real time. Unfortunately it saves the EEG output as a .sig file and the app itself is clunky and does not conduce itself to doing so. I am working with software engineers that code in python that are ready to work on it but can't until we can figure out a way to read the output of the machine in real-time. Any method to be able to figure this out would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: looking for a manual, but found this meanwhile, the image of the setup is here: http://userfile.alephnetwork.com/files/b2gmarekt_vendor/Stellate%20Harmonie%20%20E%20.pdf

Comment: How the machine is connected to the computer?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You haven't provided a link to the machine's user manual or any clue as to what interfaces are available on the EEG.

Comment: Hey Eugene: on page 8 of the document there's an image of the whole set up of the machine: http://userfile.alephnetwork.com/files/b2gmarekt_vendor/Stellate%20Harmonie%20%20E%20.pdf
Does this help?

@Transistor: I'm currently trying to find the manual, but I have linked what I could find

Comment: Python is not a very fast/efficient language. You might need some C programmers if you need real-time processing.

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to get the processed results in analog form but the inputs seem to interface between a junction box the Harmonie-E box.  [slow download Quick REf Guide](https://vdocuments.site/download/quick-reference-guide-harmonie-epdf)

(If you are trying read from program memory in real-time you need a lot more insight)  Why not deal with the factory support?

[image]

> •  Compressed spectral arrays for up to 128 channels
>   without interrupting real-time recording
>   • Spectra and band activity for up to eight user-defined bands
>   • Coherence and phase spectra to measure relationships between two channels over time
>   • Spectral activity map. Display up to eight topographical representations simultaneously
>   • Long-term trend displays of band activity, ten plots at a time

Comment: I believe the company has since gone bankrupt. And so you recommend to get the input directly from the junction box?

Comment: That's where to look for  real-time inputs

Comment: How would you get the inputs from it or do we need to find an EE or Hardware Engineer?

Comment: I don't know how it looks.

Comment: What would you need from me to be able to answer? I'm quite out of my depth, honestly

Comment: You need to find an analog expert to examine if the interface signals give you what you need.  You won’t get real-time signal processing of channels , I expect just the analog signals amplified.

Comment: What do you mean? I thought the signal would be in parallel and digital? Isn't that what the junction box does? Convert it from analog to digital?

Comment: If you say so, that’s more than I expected